# What is the recommend bandwidth for World of Warcraft?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I want to know what the recommend bandwidth for World of Warcraft. I also want to know what is actual used-bandwidth by average per seconds?

Currently I am working in Afghanistan. Here I have found some internet with about <strike>256mb/sec</strike> 256kb/sec connection. To clarify, that is <strike>mega</strike> kilobits not <strike>mega</strike> kilobytes. Is this connection suitable for limited play such as leveling and 5-man instants?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean 256 kilobits/sec? 256Mb/sec is extremely fast- good enough for streaming high def video. The average US broadband speed in 3.9Mb/s

Comment: I play on a 150kb/s connection. Major patches will take a while to download. I'd think that the average usage per second would depend heavily on how populated the world around you is.

Comment: I play WoW on a high-latency connection and I'd recommend Quartz (http://wow.curse.com/downloads/wow-addons/details/quartz.aspx), an actionbar addon that helps compensate for latency when timing spell casts.

Comment: Download will be slow, but if you find a server close to where you live you will negate a large amount of latency allowing you to a weaker broadband connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Average used bandwidth is very low.  I haven't tested it recently but it used to be possible to run WoW off a 56kbps dial-up link, implying a download rate of probably 6kBps or lower.  The latency tends to be a much greater issue, as creatures/players may not be where your client shows them as and it can impact upon spell casting delays, etc.

By the way, if that connection really is 256 mbps, that's faster than almost all of Australia and New Zealand plays WoW at - that is 32 MB/sec, and we tend to top out at 10-20 MB/sec.

Comment: I meant 256kb/sec. It has been corrected. Sorry for the error.

Comment: you also might experience "popping" in high traffic areas as your client downloads all the data for other players.

Comment: On a 256kb/sec link, leveling should be fine.  You might find you lag a bit (or a lot) in instances, as the increased traffic caused by five players and multiple mobs using abilities, etc, can have a negative game impact.